# sort a string of capital and low letters in c (by swapping)

Tags: c, string

For example: AAbbCC should be AACCbb

Everything works on the page, but for some reason, when the function swaps the values, the value of `str` changes (at the end of the running, the program prints the value of AAC)

this is my code:

```
    void capital_to_Low(char *str)
{

    int i = 0, j = (strlen(str)) -1;

    while (i < j)
    {
        if (str[i] >= 'a' && str[i] <= 'z')
        {
            swap(&str[i], &str[j--]);
        }
        else i++;

    }
    puts(str);
}

void swap(int *a, int *b)
{
    int temp;
    temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}
```

Comment: `swap` should take `char*` and not `int*`.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Good eye.. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change void swap(int *a, int *b) to void swap(char *a, char *b) , because you are referring to the address of the character not integer